# ZF2 service manager use from a custom class

Tags: zend-framework2

It looks like it has been touched several times already, but i still can't get it work. I set up an JSON-RPC server in a separate module, it works fine. Its functionality is in a new class Rpcapi. Now I want reuse DB related functions that already implemented in another module from that class. According to ZF2 docs my Rpcapi class has to be ServiceLocator-aware and it looks like I made it that way. Unfortunatelly still can't get it working. Please help keeping in mind that I'm new with ZF2 :)

Rpccontroller.php

```
 namespace Rpc\Controller;

 use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
 use Zend\Json\Server\Server;
 use Zend\Json\Server\Smd;
 use Rpc\Model\Rpcapi;

class RpcController extends AbstractActionController
{   
    public function indexAction()
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $jsonrpc = new Server();
        $jsonrpc->setClass(new Rpcapi);
        $jsonrpc->getRequest()->setVersion(Server::VERSION_2);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == "GET") {
            $smd = $jsonrpc->getServiceMap()->setEnvelope(Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);
            echo $smd;
        } else {
            $jsonrpc->handle();         
        }
    }
}
```

module.config.php for Rpc module

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'rpcapi' => 'Search\Model\SiteTable',
    ),
),
```

Rpcapi.php
        namespace Rpc\Model;

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Rpcapi implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface 
{

   protected $services;
   protected $siteTable;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->services = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->services;
    }

    public function getSiteTable()
    {
     if (!$this->siteTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->siteTable = $sm->get('rpcapi');
     }
     return $this->siteTable;
    }
        /**
        * Returns list of all sites
        * 
        *
        * @return array
        */
        public function getAllSites()
        {
        $results = $this->getSiteTable()->fetchAll();
        $r = array ('1' => '1', '2' => 2); //Just to return something for now
        return $r;
         }
}
```

All I could get out is: Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/html/AmeriFluxZF2/module/Rpc/src/Rpc/Model/Rpcapi.php on line 28. Line 28 is:
      $this->siteTable = $sm->get('rpcapi');

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `serviceLocator` to be injected by the service manager in your Rpcapi, you must get it via the service manager itself :

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'rpcapi' => 'Search\Model\SiteTable',
        'Rpc\Model\Rpcapi' => 'Rpc\Model\Rpcapi',
    ),
),
```

the action :

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $jsonrpc = new Server();
        $jsonrpc->setClass($this->getServiceLocator()->get('Rpc\Model\Rpcapi'));
        $jsonrpc->getRequest()->setVersion(Server::VERSION_2);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == "GET") {
            $smd = $jsonrpc->getServiceMap()->setEnvelope(Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);
            echo $smd;
        } else {
            $jsonrpc->handle();         
        }
    }
```

And this is where you can see that your 'rcpai' name for SiteTable is not a good choice... ;)

Comment: The good configuration should be more like this : `'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Search\Model\Site' => 'Search\Model\SiteTable',
        'Rpc\Model\Rpcapi' => 'Rpc\Model\Rpcapi',
    ),
),`

Answer (score 3):

Making the class service locator aware tells the ZF2 that the service locator should be injected into your class upon instantiation. However, you still need to use the service locator to instantiate this class, rather than creating an instance of it yourself, or this will never happen.

Your probably want to add a new entry to invokables for your `Rpcapi` class, and then grab this from the service locator instead of doing `new Rpcapi` in your controller.

PS: The naming of your classes is very confusing - you have an `Rpcapi` class, and an invokable called `rpcapi`, yet this invokable creates an instance of a completely different class?

Comment: +1 for "use the service locator to instantiate this class, rather than creating an instance of it yourself". It also might make more sense to inject `rpcapi` instance rather than the service manager